# Why is the submit button for 2captcha disabled?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha, 2captcha

I've successfully implemented captcha solving with 2captcha API up until the point where I input the answer to the hidden answer textbox.

And that's where it starts.
The "continue" button is disabled, but even when I delete "disabled" tags in the code it doesn't execute the "login" action it's supposed to execute.

```
<button disabled="" class="tw-interactive tw-button tw-button--disabled tw-button--full-width">
    <span class="tw-button__text" data-a-target="tw-button text">
        Continue
    </span>
</button>
```

^ This is the html code for the button when it's disabled [captcha not solved]

```
<button class="tw-interactive tw-button tw-button--full-width">
    <span class="tw-button__text" data-a-target="tw-button-text">
         Continue
    </span>
</button>
```

^This is avaliable "continue" button which works when Hand-doing the captcha.

When I change the code from the first to second in HTML, it enables the button but it doesn't execute any actions as I said before
Functions like element.submit() don't do anything either

I can't find info about it anywhere but I know it can be handled. The site I'm speaking of is Twitch.tv

This part of my code inputs the captcha answer into the answer textbox

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="g-recaptcha-response"]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("style", "width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; ");', elem)
print("answer: "+answer )
elem.send_keys(answer)
```

================EDIT==================

```
xlogin = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[3]/button'
recaptcha = '//*[@id="recaptcha-element-container"]/div/div/iframe'
answer=''
site_key =''
API_KEY = '#################'
stream = "ninja"
dest = "https://www.twitch.tv/" + stream

def getSiteKey(): #Gets the SITE_KEY and sets the variable
    global recaptcha,site_key
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,recaptcha)
    d = element.get_attribute("src")
    trash,rest = d.split("&k=")
    site_key,trash = rest.split("&co")
    return print("Returned site key: "+site_key) 



def handleCaptcha():
    global API_KEY, site_key,dest,answer
    s = requests.Session()
    captcha_id = s.post("http://2captcha.com/in.php?key="+API_KEY+"&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey="+site_key+"&pageurl="+dest).text.split('|')[1]
    print ("Request returned captcha ID:"+captcha_id)
    recaptcha_answer = s.get("http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={}&action=get&id={}".format(API_KEY, captcha_id)).text
    while 'CAPCHA_NOT_READY' in recaptcha_answer:
            print (recaptcha_answer)#debug
            time.sleep(5)
            recaptcha_answer = s.get("http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={}&action=get&id={}".format(API_KEY, captcha_id)).text       
    recaptcha_answer = recaptcha_answer.split('|')[1]
    print("Recaptcha answer is: "+recaptcha_answer)
    answer=recaptcha_answer
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

I tried to edit the button code manually in browser debug and couldn't get it to work. I've removed disabled attrib from the button itself and from class-> tw-button--disabled

Comment: Do you have code that actually sets up your recaptcha? You are showing the code for what it is setup as and code for how to fetch from it. But what actually sets up <button>'s properties? I think the issue is that this HTML object was copied and pasted from 2captcha but you're missing the actual API call that makes this work. The piece of could that I'm looking for should have your `KEY` in it.

Comment: I've updated my main post, thanks in advance